# Converting PDF to Dataframe using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a pdf to Dataframe, which contains tabular format. I am using Python 3.6.

Please help me to convert the same.

Please follow link for pdf file:

http://centerforcollegeaffordability.org/uploads/component-rankings-2014-v2.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I have found a way out. I am using Tabula-py binding and PyPDF2.

I am using PyPDF2 for getting number of pages in PDF and using it to iterate through each page of .pdf file.

And, Tabula is used for extracting data and converting it to dataframe.

Please correct if there is better way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tabula import read_pdf_table
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('Your Path', mode='rb'))
m = reader.getNumPages()
#print(reader)
print(m)
for i in range(m):
    n = i+1

    if n==1:
        df = read_pdf_table('Your Path', pandas_options={'header': None, 'error_bad_lines': False}, pages=n)
        index = np.where(df[0].isnull())[0]
        sect = df.iloc[index[0]:index[-1]]
        s = []
        headers = []
        for col in sect:
            colnames = sect[col].dropna().values.flatten()
            (s.insert(len(s), colnames))
            pic = [' '.join(s[col])]
            for i in pic:
                headers.append(i)
        print(df)
        df.drop(sect, inplace=True)
        df.columns = headers
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    else:
        df_2 = read_pdf_table('Your Path', pandas_options={'header': None, 'error_bad_lines': False, 'encoding': "ISO-8859-1"}, pages=n)
        df_2.drop(sect, inplace=True)
        df_2.columns = headers
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df_2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

new_df.columns = headers
print(new_df)
new_df.to_csv('Your Path', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
import tabula

# Read PDF into list of DataFrame
dataframe = tabula.read_pdf("input.pdf", pages='all')

# Read remote PDF into list of DataFrame
dataframe_2 = tabula.read_pdf("https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/raw/master/src/test/resources/technology/tabula/arabic.pdf")

# Convert PDF into CSV file
tabula.convert_into("input.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

For more information you can check this blog link:
[Click here](https://aegis4048.github.io/parse-pdf-files-while-retaining-structure-with-tabula-py)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```py
df = tabula.read_pdf('inputfile.pdf', pages='all')
  for item in df:
    for info in item.values:
      list1.append(info)
  df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
  df.to_excel('outfile.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=True)
```